# Optimizacion en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, optimización

Para mi trabajo , he creado el siguiente código ( y funciona! - aunque tarda un poco). Por desgracia, es todo menos práctico. ¿Me podrían decir alguna manera mas pro de codearlo?

Este es mi codigo: Para 21 escenarios distintos que pueden tomar valores de 1 a 5, muestra todas las combinaciones posibles. 
Ejemplos de salida:

1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1

1/1/1/1/5/1/1/1/1/1/4/1/1/1/5/5/2/3/1/2/1

5/5/5/1/5/5/5/2/2/2/4/2/3/3/5/5/2/3/1/2/1

```
    Dim a, b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, w, y, x
    Dim V(21) As Integer
    Dim texto As String
    texto = ""

    For a = 1 To 5
        V(1) = a
        For b = 1 To 5
            V(2) = b
            For c = 1 To 5
                V(3) = c
                For d = 1 To 5
                    V(4) = d
                    For f = 1 To 5
                        V(5) = f
                        For g = 1 To 5
                            V(6) = g
                            For h = 1 To 5
                                V(7) = h
                                For j = 1 To 5
                                    V(8) = j
                                    For k = 1 To 5
                                        V(9) = k
                                        For l = 1 To 5
                                            V(10) = l
                                            For m = 1 To 5
                                                V(11) = m
                                                For n = 1 To 5
                                                    V(12) = n
                                                    For o = 1 To 5
                                                        V(13) = o
                                                        For p = 1 To 5
                                                            V(14) = p
                                                            For q = 1 To 5
                                                                V(15) = q
                                                                For r = 1 To 5
                                                                    V(16) = r
                                                                    For s = 1 To 5
                                                                        V(17) = s
                                                                        For t = 1 To 5
                                                                            V(18) = t
                                                                            For u = 1 To 5
                                                                                V(19) = u
                                                                                For w = 1 To 5
                                                                                    V(20) = w
                                                                                    For y = 1 To 5
                                                                                        V(21) = y
                                                                                        For x = 1 To 21
                                                                                            texto = texto & V(x) & " / "
                                                                                        Next
                                                                                        ListBox1.Items.Add(texto)
                                                                                        texto = ""
                                                                                    Next
                                                                                Next
                                                                            Next
                                                                        Next
                                                                    Next
                                                                Next
                                                            Next
                                                        Next

                                                    Next
                                                Next
                                            Next
                                        Next
                                    Next
                                Next

                            Next
                        Next

                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: no @Pikoh.. el codigo esta bien.. es un problema de estadistica.. esta buscando todas las combinaciones de todas esas variables.. si.. va a tardar un monton con este codigo...

Comment: Algunas salidas: 1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1 ...  5/1/2/1/2/3/4/4 ... son 21 escenarios que pueden tomar valores de 1 a 5

Comment: Alguna librería debe haber con funciones estadísticas para hacer combinatoria. Digo yo.

Comment: El unico problema que veo, es que a,b,c,d,... no es nada en este codigo.. Estaria bueno saber que son, para poder construir un algoritmo que lo recorra de alguna forma eficiente...

Comment: Se podría hacer con recursividad, pero desconozco la sintaxis de VB

Comment: @abulafia recursivo va a ser todavia mas lento.... hay que solucionarlo practicamente...

Comment: Yo todavía no termino de tenerlo claro. Si hablamos de permutación de 5 elementos tomados de 21 en 21...no hablamos de 5^21 permutaciones??? no son demasiadas? (Si recuerdo bien mis matemáticas)

Comment: sip.. es eterno esto..

Comment: yo recomendaria, en este caso, que nos digas que estan tratando de hacer en tu trabajo. Esto no es muy logico que digamos...

Comment: Para un cuestionario de 21 preguntas (en las que cada una tiene un puntaje de 1 a 5) queremos estudiar las posibles respuestas. El código funciona, aunque consume mucho tiempo.

Comment: Es normal que tarde mucho tiempo, son muchismas permutaciones. Lo que yo haría sería un método (probablemente recursivo) que devolviera los resultados usando `yield`, de tal manera que cada vez que lo llames te devuelva una permutación en lugar de tener que calcular todas de golpe que obviamente siempre va a tardar. Si te interesa, mañana podría mirar algo si no has recibido ninguna respuesta antes.

Comment: Mira, algo como [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629938/579895) es exactamente lo que buscas. Solo debes convertirlo a vb.net

Comment: Gracias Pikoh. No tengo idea de C pero voy a ver si algo puedo entender.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Perdón por poner esto aqui, ya que no es propiamente una respuesta, pero es que lo que quería decir es un poco largo para un comentario. Si lo considerais necesario luego lo borro.)</sub>

Parece que tu código genera permutaciones que son cadenas con esta pinta:

```
"1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1"
```

y las añade a una lista, así:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(texto)
```

Y dices que te funciona pero tarda "un poco"... Francamente no puedo comprender cómo puede llegar a funcionar. La cantidad de elementos que estás añadiendo a esa lista, es astronómica.

Echemos unas cuentas. Cada una de esas cadenas tiene 41 caracteres de longitud, por tanto aún sin tener en cuenta posible overhead de las estructuras de datos manejadas por VB, como mínimo ocupará 41 bytes.

El número de cadenas a generar, que son las permutaciones de 5 elementos tomados de 21 en 21 con repetición, son 5<sup>21</sup>, nada menos que 476837158203125 permutaciones diferentes.

Ya que cada caso ocupa como mínimo 41 bytes y los vas guardando en una `ListBox`, la cantidad de memoria necesaria para almacenarlo todo ¡¡¡sería de 19550323486328125 bytes!!!! Usando unidades más comprensibles, serían más de 17.000 Terabytes de RAM.

¿Cómo puede funcionarte esto? Por otra parte ¿qué sentido tiene?

Creo que deberías aclarar qué pretendes al generar todas esas permutaciones. Almacenarlas acabamos de ver que es imposible.

Aún imprimirlas por pantalla sin almacenarlas sería imposible en una vida humana, pues suponiendo que puedas imprimir unas mil millones (10<sup>9</sup>) de ellas por segundo (que ya me parece algo completamente imposible, pues las operaciones de E/S no pueden ir tan rápido), la cosa tardaría unos 226 años en terminar (he hecho los números).

Así pues ¿todo esto para qué es? He leído tu comentario:

> Para un cuestionario de 21 preguntas (en las que cada una tiene un puntaje de 1 a 5) queremos estudiar las posibles respuestas. El código funciona, aunque consume mucho tiempo.

pero sigue sin aclarar en qué consiste ese estudio. Si lo único que necesitas saber es cuántas son, ya te lo he dicho antes. Si son aspectos como "cuántas contienen la respuesta 4" y similares, todas ellas se podrían calcular con fórmulas sin necesidad de generarlas todas (y encima luego procesarlas). No se me ocurre qué otra cosa puedes querer determinar. ¿Puedes ser más específico?

Comment: De todo esto lo que se deduce que el código realmente no funciona, no se puede ejecutar porque enseguida consumiría toda la memoria de la computadora